# how to determine drop down is loaded(by AJAX) an selected in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with 2 select boxes, one of which is loaded by an AJAX call. I then want to validate the elements with jquery/javascript before I enable the submit button. The jquery works fine when I change the static select (strDirectorate) but unable to get value of dropdown loaded by AJAX call.

I need to check whether people have select any item rather then first one(first item have blank value) in second drop down.

i have used jquery 1.7.2
//My first dropdown works 100% accurate

```
//Load Sub Category by Category
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#category_id").live('change', function() {
    $("#span_sub_category").html( '<img src="<?php echo $base_client;?>images/ajax-loader.gif"/>' );
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: '<?php echo $base_client;?>ajax-response.php',
        data: 'category_id='+$('#category_id').val()+'&drop_down_name=sub_category_id&operation=load_sub_category',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(obj.response==1){
                    //$('#msg_speaker_login').hide();
                    $('#span_sub_category').hide().html(obj.message).slideDown(1000);
                }else{
                    $('#span_sub_category').hide().html(obj.dd_list).slideDown(1000);
                    table_name="directory_company";
                    prepare_sorting_list();
                }
            }else{
                //JSON unable to return data.
            }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

here is the dropdown loaded by ajax call.

```
<select name="sub_category_id" id="sub_category_id">
  <option value="">Sub Category</option>
  <option value="2">Mobile Engineers</option>
  <option value="1">Motor EngineersX</option>
  <option value="3">Chemical Engineers</option>
</select>
```

now in a submit button click event i try to check whether sub_category_id is loaded and selected non blank value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnKeywordSaveUpdate').live('click', function() {
     if(typeof("sub_category_id") != "undefined")
       alert("Sub category not loaded");
     else if($('#sub_category_id').val()=="")
       alert("Please select sub category");
     alert(msg);
  });
});
```

finally, my problem is: i always get alert("Sub category not loaded"); but i sub category drop down is loaded into my page and i have select a non blank value. so, how do i check whether sub category drop down is loaded into page and selected or not.

Comment: `typeof("sub_category_id")` will always = `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if(typeof("sub_category_id") != "undefined")` to `if(typeof("sub_category_id") == "undefined")` or remove it altogether. `if(typeof("sub_category_id") != "undefined")` is going to return string anyway

change you code to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnKeywordSaveUpdate').live('click', function() {
     if($('#sub_category_id').length == 0)
       alert("Sub category not loaded");
     else if($('#sub_category_id').val()=="")
       alert("Please select sub category");
     alert(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it accomplished what you required

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use `live` as it's deprecated. Use `on` with a delegate. Secondly, your `typeof("sub_category_id")` will always be `string`, hence why you always see 'Sub category not loaded'. Also, you should use `length` to check if an element exists. With that in mind try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnKeywordSaveUpdate', function() {
    if (!$("#sub_category_id").length) {
        alert("Sub category not loaded");
    }
    else if ($('#sub_category_id').val() == "") {
        alert("Please select sub category");
    }

    alert(msg); // Where does message come from?
});
```

Note, I used `document` here for the delegate handler, really you should use the closest element which is not dynamically appended.

Comment: so far i know, live is deprecated from Jquery 1.9 or 1.8. and i use here 1.7.2 which works fine for loading drop down by an AJAX Call.

Comment: It may work fine, but you'll have issues if you upgrade jQuery, and it's also not very performant. The code within the click handler can be transferred though and will work with `live` too.